# Does kubernetes support setting up cluster with on-premise GPU machines

Tags: docker, kubernetes, job-scheduling, kubeflow

We're buying GPU machines nowadays and going to use them for running ML training. Planned system architecture which consist of `producer`, `queue` and N*`workers` is that:

1. Having `producer` (kind of master) which enqueue training request to queue.
2. N `workers` which monitor the queue so that it pulls requests if any and then running training.

My questions is about setting workers, which should be running on GPU machines we'll buy. So I wonder if kubernetes supports setting up cluster via on-premise GPU machines.

Best,

Comment: Kubernetes does support Nvidia and AMD GPUs via device plugins. You can specifically schedule pods as per your needs. This is good reference point. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/

Comment: @Sanket Sudake Could you please post your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted community wiki for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

Kubernetes supports accessing node's GPU (AMD or NVIDIA) via [Device Plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#using-device-plugins).

Worth noting that this support is experimental for now.

> Kubernetes includes experimental support for managing AMD and NVIDIA GPUs (graphical processing units) across several nodes.

For more information please see [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/).